# Jokes with "une salope, une connasse, une emmerdeuse"

Tags: sens, argot

Are there several jokes in french which are constructed on "une salope, une connasse, une emmerdeuse" as in this joke below:

> Quelle est la différence entre une connasse, une salope et une
>   emmerdeuse?  La connasse baise avec tout le monde sauf avec toi, la
>   salope avec tout le monde et aussi avec toi et l'emmerdeuse, seulement
>   avec toi !

If yes, can you explain the context? I didn't get much of it, especially the emmerdeuse part.

Comment: Please note that this kind of jokes is now (discriminatory, sexist,...) less and less tolerated so be very careful when, where and with whom you use it. In doubt, don't.

Comment: To actually answer your question, no there's not many jokes constructed like this (that I know of). There's not much variation you can do with it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is a bitch, the second a slut and the third your wife.

Comment: Actually, the third is actually more "a pain in the neck" in the joke but subtly said to be your wife (and that's the point of the joke).

Answer (score 1):

Complément à la réponse. Ici

http://pteu.fr/doku.php?id=humour:devinettes

Tu peux trouver d'autres devinettes dans le même esprit (discriminatoire, sexiste, etc.) lesquelles je te suggérerais de ne pas utiliser:-)!

(Voir ici https://blog.francetvinfo.fr/ladies-and-gentlemen/2013/09/17/connasse-la-nouvelle-invention-des-decomplexe-es-du-sexisme.html)

Answer (score 1):

Laissant la plaisanterie à d'autres, je me limiterais à la partie de la question  demandant une  réponse sur le plan des différences, et j'essaierai de cerner quelque peu le sens et le  contexte d'utilisation de ces mots.
Tout d'abord, il faut savoir que jugés sur le point de vue de qui les utilise, il n'y a aucune différence entre les trois, ce sont essentiellement des termes d'homme.

Il n'y a pas de différence entre les deux premiers termes en ce qui concerne certaines personnes qui les utilisent, essentiellement des hommes en colère qui disent un peu n'importe quoi ; pour d'autres il y a une différence et elle définit les deux mots.
 Le premier mot caractérise soit une femme qui est infidèle à son mari ou à son amant d'une façon très sournoise, ou une femme qui passe d'homme en homme facilement, soit une femme dont les pratiques dans ses rapports avec les gens sont immorales (mensonge, tromperie, etc.).
Les femmes qui sont caractérisées par le second terme sont plutôt des femmes qui ont tendance à avoir des opinions allant à l'encontre de celles de l'homme, qui ont leur propre manière de faire les choses et qui ne cèdent pas facilement à la volonté des hommes, cela étant loin d'être limité aux questions d'appariement entre les deux sexes.
 Qu'il s'agisse d'hommes de la première sorte ou de la seconde sorte, on ne peut pas leur donner beaucoup de crédit pour ce qu'ils disent en prononçant ces mots avant de savoir vraiment ce qu'ils ont à dire et ils n'ont souvent rien d'autre à dire ; ce ne sont pas nécessairement des personnes dont le jugement est à respecter, ils se trouveront avoir tort dans une certaine partie des cas.

Le troisième terme, toujours vulgaire, —beaucoup de monde lui préfèrera l'euphémisme « enquiquineuse » bien que Brassens, lui, pour le besoin de ses descriptions aura jugé bon d'ajouter  un surenchérissement dans le terme « emmerderesse »— l'est moins que les deux premiers mais ne dénote pas dans le parler d'un homme une culture bien digne de ce nom ; un homme qui ne sait pas  décrire le comportement d'une personne avec autre chose qu'un terme grossier, sans expliquer de quoi il s'agit, ne peut pas se recommander  dans l'esprit de ceux capables de peser le pour et le contre. C'est un terme qui s'apparente au second, et il est plus traditionnel, d'où l'habitude qu'ont les gens de s'en servir assez couramment. Il reflète ce que le sexe fort a toujours considéré comme une certaine obstination dans le comportement du sexe faible, une obstination qu'il a à subir occasionnellement et que certains aiment à traduire par ce troisième terme. Il n'est plus question de moralité dans le sens de ce troisième terme mais du seul fait qu'il y a des femmes qui tiennent tête à l'homme et en particulier à l'homme de leur vie. Avec juste raison ou non ces femmes-là sont catégorisées dans un parler abrupt par ce troisième terme.